# Probability of having an even number of a specific face value of a die

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Here is the question: Given a fair die rolled $n$ times, what is the probability of having an even number of $6$s?

My approach: 
$$\Omega = \{(x_{1}, x_{2}, ..., x_{n}) :1 \le  x_{i} \le 6\}$$
So $$|\Omega| = 6^{n}$$
Since the probability is space is a finite uniform one, $$P(A) = \frac{|A|}{|\Omega|}$$
Let $A_{i}$ be the event that there are exactly $i$ sixes in the $n$-tuple. Then, $$A = \bigcup\limits_{i=0}^{\lceil{(n-1)/2}\rceil} A_{2*i}$$ Since these events are disjoint, $$P(A) = P(\bigcup\limits_{i=0}^{\lceil{(n-1)/2}\rceil} A_{2*i}) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{\lceil{(n-1)/2}\rceil} P(A_{2*i})$$
Now, $|A_{i}| = \binom{n}{i} * 5^{n-i}$. Hence, $$P(A) = \frac{1}{6^n} \sum\limits_{i=0}^{\lceil{(n-1)/2}\rceil} \binom{n}{2i} * 5^{n-2i}$$ As a side note, when I fed this sum into wolfram alpha engine, it couldn't compute it.

The book however says the anwer is $$\frac{1}{2}(1 + (\frac{2}{3})^{n})$$
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is fine and correct, but may not yield the most convenient form of the answer.  Instead, perhaps you could approach via a recurrence relation.  Let $p_n$ be the probability of having an even number of sixes after $n$ rolls.

For $n+1$ rolls of the dice, for there to be an even number of sixes the final die must be a six and the previous $n$ dice must have an odd number of sixes **or** the final die must not be a six while the previous $n$ dice must have an even number of sixes.

This yields the recurrence relation: $p_{n+1} = \frac{1}{6}(1-p_n)+\frac{5}{6}p_n = \frac{1}{6}+\frac{2}{3}p_n$

Using an initial condition of $p_0=1$ (*or the initial condition $p_1=\frac{5}{6}$ if you dislike starting at zero for whatever reason*), we can solve the recurrence relation for a closed form solution which will agree with the answer given by the book.

---

$p_{n}=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{2}{3}p_{n-1}$

characteristic polynomial of associated homogeneous equation:  $x-\frac{2}{3}=0$, thus the general part is of the form $c_1 (\frac{2}{3})^n$

non-homogeneous piece is a constant (*and no general part is of the same form*) so particular piece is also a constant.  Solving for that constant:  $k = \frac{1}{6}+\frac{2}{3}k \implies \frac{1}{3}k=\frac{1}{6}\implies k=\frac{1}{2}$

So, we have $p_n = \frac{1}{2}+c_1(\frac{2}{3})^n$.  Using our initial condition that $p_0=1$ we find $c_1=\frac{1}{2}$

Thus:  $$p_n=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot (\frac{2}{3})^n$$

Comment: Didn't even think of using the characteristic polynomial...
Thank you!

Comment: Could you please clarify why the non-homogeneous piece is required to be a constant? Or is it that the constant function is one solution?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @sergei it must match the order of the nonhomogeneous part of the linear recurrence and be linearly independent of the homogeneous solution.  See any reference on the subject for more details and proof.

Comment: @JMoravitz How do you decide apriori that a recurrence relation approach would be useful here? Just experience or something else?

Comment: @Alex largely experience.  The recurrence relation approach is functionally equivalent to using markov chains and using matrices instead, the states being either having an even number vs having an odd number of sixes.  At the time of writing this I was teaching markov chains so it was fresh in my mind.